# What type of garage door seal is this?

Tags: insulation, garage-door, seal

Is this a type I cannot find, or is this just a normal flat rubber type that has been shoved into the kerf cut, folded over, and stapled?

If the latter is the case, any idea why someone would do it this way, or is this common? 
[image]

Comment: Almost looks like original 1960's issue or something of that timeframe. It is only tattered looking because of the way it was pulled on to tear it off short to have it in the state is now.... It used to be stapled onto the back of its mounting, that is the way it was done. Isherwood has the remedy for it. Your mounting strip is probably larger than the new stuff, so you will need to do some touch up painting. I have also seen the new added right over the original mounting/backing strip, a little tacky in my mind, but it gets past painting.

Comment: The house was built in 1979.  I think you guys are correct.  I don't see why they made the kerf cut to stick the rubber seal in, but it does look like the goal was essentially what can be bought today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell what I'm looking at from that one photo, but it may have been someone's attempt at a homemade version of the common commercial weather seal that you see on modern overhead doors.

I'd probably remove it entirely and start fresh. 3 pieces of vinyl molding with rubber gasket will probably cost under $25.